# Get specific time period from a list of epoch in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, epoch

I have the following table with epoch timestamps in Postgres. I would like to select the timestamps where the time is from **20:00 to 21:00 in PST**. I have tried the following partially but I can't seem to extract both hour and minutes.

`SELECT timestamp from table where extract(‘hour’ from to_timestamp(created_at) at time zone ‘America/Los_angeles’) > 20`

| **created_at**  |

| 1526528788 |

| 1526442388 |

| 1526309188 |

| 1526359588 |

| 1526532388 |

| 1526489188 |

**Expected result:**

| **created_at**  |

| 1526528788 |

| 1526442388 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you write `America/Los Angeles` when you mean `PST`? They are (sometimes) different.

Does that solve your problem:

```
... WHERE extract(hour FROM
                  to_timestamp(1526309188) AT TIME ZONE 'PST'
                 ) BETWEEN 20 AND 21;
```

Comment: Hi Laurenz, with the above solution, I'm getting timestamps after 21:00. I would like to get all timestamps from 20:00 to 21:00 only. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: I don't think so. Can you give me an example?